# PyQt5 GUI runs with no errors but window doesn't appear

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

The problem is that when I run the PyQt5 GUI after adding resource file and adding PushButtons with border-images on them, mainwindow does not launch and no errors either.

I converted the main window UI to Python with following command:

```
pyuic5 mainWindow.iu -o mainWindow.py
```

So this is the mainWindow in python.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import resources_rc
#import sys
#import random
#import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
#from PyQt5 import QtCore
#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QMessageBox, QWidget
#from numpy import arange, sin, pi
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
#from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1108, 672)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);")
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1050, 0, 21, 611))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.verticalScrollBar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.verticalScrollBar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        self.horizontalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 610, 1051, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.horizontalScrollBar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setObjectName("horizontalScrollBar")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, -30, 151, 141))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/NM_State_University_logo.png);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.house1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(31, 31, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.house1.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house1.setText("")
        self.house1.setObjectName("house1")
        self.house2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(258, 31, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house2.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house2.setText("")
        self.house2.setObjectName("house2")
        self.house3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(484, 31, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house3.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house3.setText("")
        self.house3.setObjectName("house3")
        self.house4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(711, 31, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house4.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house4.setText("")
        self.house4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.house4.setObjectName("house4")
        self.house6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(258, 200, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house6.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house6.setText("")
        self.house6.setObjectName("house6")
        self.house5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(31, 200, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house5.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house5.setText("")
        self.house5.setObjectName("house5")
        self.house9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(31, 368, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house9.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house9.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house9.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house9.setText("")
        self.house9.setObjectName("house9")
        self.house7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(484, 200, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house7.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house7.setText("")
        self.house7.setObjectName("house7")
        self.house8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(711, 200, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house8.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house8.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house8.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house8.setText("")
        self.house8.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 20))
        self.house8.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.house8.setObjectName("house8")
        self.house11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(484, 368, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house11.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house11.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house11.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house11.setText("")
        self.house11.setObjectName("house11")
        self.house10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(258, 368, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house10.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house10.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house10.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house10.setText("")
        self.house10.setObjectName("house10")
        self.house12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(711, 368, 32, 16))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house12.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house12.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house12.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house12.setText("")
        self.house12.setObjectName("house12")
    #####################################Power Plot House 1
        self.PowPlotHouse1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.PowPlotHouse1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 171, 121))
        self.PowPlotHouse1.setObjectName("PowPlotHouse1")
    #####################END of widge
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1108, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuOptions = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuOptions.setObjectName("menuOptions")
        self.menuAdmin = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAdmin.setObjectName("menuAdmin")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionSave_As = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_As.setObjectName("actionSave_As")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_As)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOptions.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAdmin.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuOptions.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Options"))
        self.menuAdmin.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Admin"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave_As.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save As"))

import resources_rcenter
```

I converted my resources file the following way:

```
pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py
```

And my resources file contents

```
 <RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png</file>
    <file>img/Gohomenew.png</file>
    <file>img/NM_State_University_logo.png</file>
    <file>img/NMlogo_1colorstate_black.png</file>
    <file>img/NMSU.png</file>
    <file>img/Search_in_home.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

This is the result when trying to run it.

[image: ScreenShot]

I think about writing an exception to see if it catches anything.

Comment: what is `resources_rcenter`?

Comment: Where are you creating the application with QApplication?

Comment: typo when writing the question, but its my resource file . It is commented out at bottom of the file and declared all the way at the top  eyllanesc

Comment: resources_rc.py or resources_rcenter.py ?

Comment: I have not modified the code from when I turned it from ui to py file. exepct for commenting out the resources file at bottom of the file.

Comment: where is the constructor? add at the end if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = yourclasshere()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: eyllanesc, it is resources_rc.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the path you use is incorrect, this is caused by the prefix that you do not add.

For example you must change:

```
self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/NM_State_University_logo.png);")
```

to:

```
self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/newPrefix/img/NM_State_University_logo.png);")
```

But the above can be tedious, a better way is to change the prefix to `"/"`, in that case it should look like this:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png</file>
    <file>img/Gohomenew.png</file>
    <file>img/NM_State_University_logo.png</file>
    <file>img/NMlogo_1colorstate_black.png</file>
    <file>img/NMSU.png</file>
    <file>img/Search_in_home.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And then you recompilas with `pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py`.

Another problem is that not for an application to be launched in pyqt you must create the application, for this I recommend adding the following to your file mainWindow.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: eyllanesc, Your answer worked !! Thank you very much.

Comment: eyllanesc, I did not marked it useful because I don't have enough reputation points. But thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the mistype resources_rc and don't forget to create main.py file to call MainWindow.py.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from MainWindow import *
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    instance = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then run main.py